# Do exactly what I tell you!

Tags: riddle, wordplay, lateral-thinking, acrostic

A short and simple one for the community while I work on the next big one!

---

> Do exactly what I tell you.
>
> ---
>
> Stop.
>
> ---
>
> Ask me if you see the **moon**.
>
> That, over there; pick it **up**.
>
> State your name, for the **record**.
>
> - Keep it separate.
>
> Mentor me in simple **English**.
>
> - Add two more, then hide it from me.
>
> ---
>
> Continue.
>
> ---
>
> Find a nervous man, then tell him this:
>
> - *O*bviously, *p*eople *p*ry; *o*ften *s*taying *I*n *t*emporary *e*nclosures.

### Hints

> Look to the **right**.
>  Take only **one**.
>  Four **letters** needed.
>  Destroy just one **word**.
>  In bold what you want.
>  An acrostic its not.
>  The bullets are suggestions, proposals, or pleas.

The acrostic found in the final statement does not apply to the following hints, nor do the following hints apply to the hints above.

> The opposites you seek are not exact opposites.
>  They are similar yet the *opposite* of what was given.
>  The acrostic isn't a true acrostic, but a crafted one.
>  The bullets are instructions and only help to create the answer.

Comment: I stopped.  Now what?

Comment: @Alex hahaha :P

Comment: I keep coming back to this one, but assuming the path i'm on: zbbahc orpbzrf fhaqbja ohg erpbeq naq ratyvfu ner uneq gb svaq bccbfvgrf sbe . I think having that would make the suggestions make more sense, but every variation I try comes up short

Comment: @JGibbers You're taking the wrong approach; pay close attention to the hints there and use the same logic on those as well. Feel free to comment your ideas on occasion and I'll try to help without giving away the answer. :)

Answer (score 10):

I know this isn't it, but I got on this train of though and couldn't get off. Not a real guess but I had fun with it

> Opposites comes out of the last line, so we need to do the opposite. And clearly this means beatles songs are the opposite of each line!

Do exactly what I tell you.

> Think for youself

Ask me if you see the moon.

> Here comes the sun

That, over there; pick it up.

> Don't let met down

State your name, for the record.

> I call your name or You Know My Name (Look Up the Number)

Mentor me in simple English.

> Ob-La-Di Ob-La-Da is gibberish, the opposite of english

Add two more, then report back to me.

> Let it be is the opposite of doing something

Continue.

> Stop

Find a nervous man, then tell him this:

Obviously, people pry; often staying in temporary enclosures.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! +1 From me as this was a great answer! I love The Beatles, and I can definitely see me doing one like this in the future; however, as you stated, this is not the answer. Very good find on the horizontal acrostic! You're on to something there, a bit of lateral thinking will be required to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

## Partial Answer

> As found by @JGibbers the horizontal acrostic in the last line spells opposites, and since the hint and bolding points us to the last words that's where I am starting.

Ask me if you see the **moon**.

> opposite of moon is sun

That, over there; pick it **up**.

> opposite of up is down

State your name, for the **record**.

- Keep it separate.

  > Currently thinking withdraw as a possibility and from the hint of four letters needed, destroy just one word and keep it separate I believe we only use with or draw

Mentor me in simple **English**.

- Add two more, then hide it from me.

  > maybe add two letters to English (or its opposite) and ignore part of the word or the message is telling the person to hide this object/thing?

Overall:

> Currently thinking it is some kind of message for a duel at sun down, hence the man being nervous.

Comment: I would love to say you're closing in, but this couldn't be farther from the answer. Though the idea of a duel at sun down is pretty cool! As I told @JGibbers, pay close attention to those hints if you're using them. Utilize that acrostic.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a wild guess:

> Mats

Step 1:

> JGibbers found "Opposite"

---

Main text:

Ask me if you see the moon.

> Honestly, I just can't seem to pull much meaning from these core lines, like at all. So jump down the "Hints" because this is mostly me saying "I don't know" here.
>  I guess here I could get "tell you I see the sun".

That, over there; pick it up.

> Put something down?

State your name, for the record.

> No idea what the opposite of this would be.

- Keep it separate.

  > Put it together. But what is it?

Mentor me in simple English.

> Uh...

- Add two more, then hide it from me.

  > Subtract two more? Add not two? Subtract some number?
  >  Then show it to you in spoiler text because we should have the answer!

---

**The Hints:**

Look to the right.

> Anyways, this is the section I'm actually using to get my probably-wrong-but-what-they-hay answer. Oh, and I decided to try the opposite of all these hints.
>  Look to the left.

Take only one.

> First letter of first word.
>  Huh, okay maybe not the opposite of this one... too late now!

Four letters needed.

> First letter of first four major lines: A, T, S, M
>  Or this one... If I hadn't already typed all this out, I'd reconsider.

Destroy just one word.

> Put them together to get a word.

In bold what you want.

> We want the first word because it's on the opposite side of the sentence where the bold words are?

An acrostic its not.

> Oh but it is...

The bullets are suggestions, proposals, or pleas.

> Eh, demands? I don't know here...

Comment: Heyyy you're on to something there! :D +1 I'll add another hint. :)

Answer (score -2):

Here is my solution to this:

> OK, I stopped.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/38245)

Comment: I do not intend to either critique, or request clarification from the author. This is my answer, which I believe satisfies the specification of the question. Things in Puzzling never have austere specification rules, of course, but I believe my perspective is valid enough.